# Why do these HMTL5 data attributes return a function instead of the assigned values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I'm using jQuery to retrieve and set my data attribute. I've tried to set data value with `attr()` and `data()` as well:

```
$("#select2").attr("data-myval", "true");
$("#select2").data("myval", "true");
```

Neither is working, and it returns with a function if I `console.log()` it. What is the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select1 = $("#select1").data("myval");
  var select2 = $("#select2").data("myval");

  console.log(select1);
  console.log(select2);

  $("#select1").click(function() {
    $(this).children("p").css("display", "block");
    $("#select2").data("myval", "true");
  });

  if (select2 == "true") {
    $("#select2").click(function() {
      $(this).children("p").css("display", "block");
    });
  } else {

  }
});
```

```css
#select1,
#select2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.ex p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ex" id="select1" data-myval="true">
  <p>Text1</p>
</div>
<div class="ex" id="select2" data-myval="false">
  <p>Text2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"And why is a new blue rectangle in stackoverflows editor which overlaps my example?"* Because it uses a `div` for the snippet console.

Comment: I've added a class to your `div` and the styling for it so we can have the snippet console in the example.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this code?

Comment: Regulate certain click event's order of the user.

Comment: Sorry, that's not at all clear. "Regulate" them how? What should clicks do?

Comment: Until the user not clicks the first select, the next  select will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no events order here, there is only one event for the first box. The event for the second box will never be attached because the `if (select2 == "true")` is `false` when `$(document).ready` and it is Boolean not string anyway. You can move it to inside the event and change it to `if ($(this).data("myval"))`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select1").click(function() {
    $(this).children("p").css("display", "block");
    $("#select2").data("myval", "true");
  });

  $("#select2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("myval")) {
      $(this).children("p").css("display", "block");
    } else {

    }
  });
});
```

```css
#select1,
#select2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.ex p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ex" id="select1" data-myval="true">
  <p>Text1</p>
</div>
<div class="ex" id="select2" data-myval="false">
  <p>Text2</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can add the second even inside the first event, but to avoid adding it several times if you click on the first box several times, you must remove it with `off("click")` first then add it.